# Cumulative Distribution Function of a Die

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Im trying to understand this question:

Find the cumulative distribution function of the outcome of a single die roll that has the number 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, and 12. Also draw a graph.

All I have came up with is that the E(x) = 7.014
p= 1/6

So would I add up all the probabilities of each outcome? Say the probability of outcome of 2 is 1/6; the outcome of 4 is 2/6; outcome of 6 is 3/6.... and so on? After i get each cumulative probability, how do i find the Cumulative Distribution Function?

Comment: Question: Do you roll the die two times ?

Comment: In this example, the die is rolled just once.

Comment: Is it a 6-sided dice with the numbers 2,4,6,8,10,12 ?

Comment: interesting die at any case))

Comment: The cumulative probability distribution function $F_X(x)$ of a discrete random variable $X$ taking on values $x_1 < x_2 < \cdots$ with probabilities $p_1, p_2, \ldots$ respectively is a _staircase_ function that rises from $0$ at $x=-\infty$ to $1$ at $x=\infty$ with _rises_ of $p_i$ at $x_i$, $i = 1, 2, \ldots$. The steps themselves are of widths $x_{i+1}-x_i$, that is, $F_X(x)$ has value $p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_i$ for $x \in [x_i,x_{i+1})$. Pay attention to the $[$ and $)$ in that last sentence: they are important. In your problem, $F_X(x)=0$ for $x\in (-\infty,0)$ and $1$ for $x \in [12,\infty)$.

Comment: Yes it is a six sided die with those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So would I add up all the probabilities of each outcome? Say the
> probability of outcome of 2 is 1/6; the outcome of 4 is 2/6; outcome
> of 6 is 3/6.... and so on?

The probability of $X\leq 2$ is 1/6. The probability of $X \leq 4$ is 2/6. It is always smaller or equal.

$F(x)=\begin{cases} 0, \ x < 2  \\ 1/6, \ 2\leq  x  <4 \\ 2/6, \ 4\leq  x  <6 \\ 3/6, \ 6\leq  x  <8 \\ 4/6, \ 8\leq  x  <10 \\ 5/6, \ 10\leq  x  <12 \\ 1, \   x \geq 12     \end{cases}$

Comment: so the cumulutive function shows all cumulative possibilities of each outcome?

Comment: $P(X\leq 4)=2/6$ means, that the probability to roll a number smaller or equal 4 is 2/6. Thus in this case it is the probability for 2 outcomes, if you do not consider the outcomes, which have the probability=0, like X=3.32.

Comment: Could I say that the CDF is f(x) = x/6, if 2<= x <= 12; f(x) = 0, if x<2 or x> 12.

Comment: I would take intervals, because F(3)=1/6. I made an edit. Ask, if something is not clear.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense! I appreciate you clearing that up.